# C#, ASP.NET / Tutorial /Different Button

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I was following this tutorial:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-on-off-button/

I would like everything the same except I would like to change:

```
   <section>  
    <a rel="external" href="#button" id="button">&#xF011;</a>  
    <span></span>  
   </section>
```

to:

```
<section>
            <asp:Button CssClass="button" id="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button3_Click" Text="&quot;\uf011;&quot;" />
            <span></span>
                </section>
```

Because of simpler adding buttons and then programming them. Everything works OK, just when I click the button it doesn't become white and the red dot doesn't become green, I guess it's because in the tutorial is button used like a link, and if I add it with visual studio it's not a link, what could I do that i woul style the button like that even if I add it with visual studio.

Comment: change it to use your css class name (button) instead of anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a hyperlink you should use LinkButton element. `Button` component shows a button element. `LinkButton` is rendered as a hyperlink with  some extra properties.

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="button" id="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button3_Click" Text="&quot;\uf011;&quot;" />
```

Also you can try the following code in order to have code-behind capabilities for a stanrdard `a` tag.

```
<section>  
    <a rel="external" href="#button" id="button" runat="server">&#xF011;</a>  
    <span></span>  
</section>
```

Another option is using `HyperLink` component

```
<section>  
    <asp:HyperLink Text="&#xF011;" rel="external" href="#button" id="button" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>  
    <span></span>  
</section>
```

You should pay attention to anchor's id attribute. I mean, The id attributes are prepended with `MainContent_` if you have not set it to be shown only with the value you gave.

There are two options for this:

1. Change jQuery's selector from `$('#button')` to `$('#MainContent_button')`
2. Change .NET settings for showing your elements without prepending `MainContent_` prefix.

Comment: I tried this, but doesnt work, maybe it is not problem that button is link, i just cant find out why doesnt work, i make evrything the same, just that change,

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i reprogramed it: 
- When click button from aspx.cs call another css file, to restyle the button,

Comment: @user3226944 your solution causes a post-back.